# BIM 360 DATA CONNECTOR SOURCE CODE IN C SHARP

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, powerbi-custom-data-connector

We are developing a web application with C Sharp as backend, We trying to integrate BIM 360 data connector in our application, For which, can anyone share a sample BIM 360 data connector source code in `C#`?

Comment: Yes I did, but I found sample code in node js only, I'm not familiar with that. So I need in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this PDF, has code for .NET Core and .NET Framework:

[Connect to Fusion Team & BIM 360 data](https://file.smarteventscloud.com/fileDownload/B2BC0F3298081DFF89D5AC729339609E81528F17DDF8C4D5BED36962ED78D08E36FC922EC19E810DEAF3780920CAF2F72B21550841DAD01E83280F9025C05BCCFA891B63681CCEE34EBA2460521C802DE1754FD47AAB442BEC0A6112499269FBFE923EDE78EF375D2BCDB8E17CFBCB73B874A5D89BF6CCC5A1061D0DFA1F11C2B3BF35FDE039E93240DB920EEFC2B30160B62B4399DB360C4CD7601ACCACAC791A4A3A019521B94B6584300141852B7279733ADE8FF92B5BFF15E00C9210E39B/6597B37EAF2BAB94297706B31EA00C06EC865EBC802655BA3BDD7AC5B42E7FAFEB5DD73C2C86299AA2EC0E45472C6375.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, Leandro, It was really helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The material Leandro shared has been the learning tutorial at:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels
which introduces how to build application of Forge to connect BIM 360 model documents step-by-step.

While my understanding is what you are looking for is on how to use Data Connector API in .NET. As far as I know, our Forge team has not sample in .NET, but has samples in Node.js (which is also based on the skeleton of learning tutorial above)
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-data.connector.dashboard

In addition, we also provided Postman collection for  Data Connector API:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-data.connector.api-postman.collection
In Postman, code snippet in various languages (including .NET)) is available. It might be a reference for you to build the final application:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: If you are the owner of any of this code that you referenced, you should specify this. Why do you say "we also provided" ?

Comment: what I meant is although we have not .NET sample for Data Connector API at this moment, the Postman collection may be probably helpful because it has Code Snippet feature. This feature can show the snippet of the endpoint of API in languages such as Restsharp (in C#). These snippet could be merged to the LearnForge tutorial skeleton, as I did in Node.js.